# How to reload a C# Public Void (code behind) method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a method Public void which is getting the data from the back-end store procedure.

```
 public void LoadContactDetails()
        {
             sTemplateID = hfPayorNameContact.Value; 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = oService.GetServiceAgreement_TemplatePayorDetails(sTemplateID);
            tablecontact = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PAYOR_CONTACT"].ToString();
        }
```

At first when the page is load, the "sTemplateID" will be null. The process I want is when the user input the name it will pass it in "sTemplateID". Then after that the data will be load in the table, but the data sTemplateID that it getting is still null. It is working when you already put a string name in the "sTemplateID" for example sTemplateID = "PayorName"; it loads the table of PayorName. So I was planning that whenever the user change inputed name it will also load the table depends on the name inputted.

I was expecting to load the table depends on the user inputted name.

Comment: this is web application. it is asp.net web forms.

Comment: Can you post the .aspx and .aspx.cs?

Comment: You don't reload a method. That's not an actual concept. If your value being used by the method isn't what you think it is, you need to trace back and figure out what touches that variable.

Comment: ok, so the user enters some value etc., how does that value get transferred from that user input to your hidden field called hfPayorNameContact?

Comment: it transfer like this document.getElementById("hfPayorNameContact").value = $("#txtPayorDescriptionName").val();